# Issue on TextView width when creating my own TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I created my own TextView by extending the TextView class in order to improve its display. I created various Paint and stuff to add a kind of margin. Then text has to be displayed right after the margin. If I set

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

the display is ok and my line is fully filled with a white background (as defined in my layout).
BUT if I set

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

the display goes wrong and the end of the text of my TextView is cropped. I guess this is due to the fact that I made a Translate in the onDraw method of my TextView but I don't know how to fix it.
Please note that I need the set wrap_content because I want to add another TextBox right after, and a LinearLayout around both, but for the moment the other TextBox erase a part of the content of the first one.

The code of my new TextBox is the following one :

```
package com.flo.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.flo.musicalnotes.R;

public class NoteItemTextView extends TextView {

// Properties
private Paint marginPaint;
private Paint linePaint;
private Paint circlePaint;
private int paperColor;
private float margin;
private float marginEnd;
private float textStart;

// Initialization
public NoteItemTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.Init(context);
}

public NoteItemTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.Init(context);
}

private void Init(Context context)
{
    // Resources retrieval
    Resources myResources  = getResources();

    // Brush definition
    this.marginPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    this.marginPaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.marginColor));
    this.marginPaint.setStrokeWidth((float) 1.8);

    this.linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    this.linePaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.underlineColor));

    this.circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    this.circlePaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.marginColor));
    this.circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    // various resources
    this.paperColor = myResources.getColor(R.color.bgColor);
    this.margin = myResources.getDimension(R.dimen.marginSize);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();            
    int ot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    switch(ot)
    {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            this.marginEnd = this.margin + metrics.widthPixels / 100;
            this.textStart = this.marginEnd + metrics.widthPixels / 100;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            this.marginEnd = this.margin + metrics.heightPixels / 100;
            this.textStart = this.marginEnd + metrics.heightPixels / 100;
        default:
            this.marginEnd = this.margin + 5;
            this.textStart = this.marginEnd + 10;
    }
}

//@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
    // paper color
    canvas.drawColor(this.paperColor);

    // lines drawing
    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), this.linePaint);

    // marge drawing
    canvas.drawLine(this.margin,  0,  this.margin, getMeasuredHeight(), this.marginPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(this.marginEnd,  0,  this.marginEnd, getMeasuredHeight(), this.marginPaint);

    double x = (this.textStart + this.marginEnd) / 1.8;
    float y1 = getMeasuredHeight() / 3;
    float y2 = getMeasuredHeight() * 2 / 3;
    float radius = (float) 2.5;
    canvas.drawCircle((float) x, y1, radius, this.circlePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle((float) x, y2, radius, this.circlePaint);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(this.textStart, 0);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();   
}
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code to your custom textview class

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName() , String.format("height x %s ::: width x %s ",height , width));
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        //Extra space after last letter.
        float px = 2 * density;
        int adjustedWidth = (int) (width + textStart + px);
        setMeasuredDimension(adjustedWidth, height);

    }
```

Comment: god damn impressive, it works perfectly !! Could you please explain me why to use this px = 2 * density ?

Comment: Its just for a little padding after the last character , otherwise the last character will not shown properly. If you satisfied with my answer please accept the answer.

Comment: i'd like to do so, but i don't know how to accept it . . .

Comment: Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your textview

```
android:paddingRight="25dp"
```

Comment: you added it in the xml ? I tried your code, and its working ofr me. Is your textview rightaligned ? , then it should be paddingLeft="25dp"

Comment: doesn't work, sorry. But Krish's answer is good ! Anyway thanks !